# spss.system.file in package memisc add extra empty columns when importing string variables

Tags: r, import, spss

I have used the `spss.system.file` function in the `memisc` package a few times before, and it's always worked without error. However, recently I've tried importing several SPSS files which contain String variables. It seems that whenever I use `spss.system.file` to import these variables, it results in 6 extra columns of empty space. For example, if the following character vector was a String variable in SPSS named Age:

```
Age <- c("18 years old", "18 years old", "24", "19 years old", "18", "18")
```

Reading it in to R with `spss.system.file` would result in an R `data.frame` (after converting from `data.set`) with an `Age` variable containing the actual data (of class `factor`) and then `Age0`, `Age1`, ... `Age6` - all of class `factor`, but all completely empty.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue or an idea of what causes it? I know that potentially converting the SPSS file to a `portable` file might make the read in better, but that requires having SPSS installed.

Comment: I have the same using spss.get in Hmisc. No idea what causes it, though

Comment: update: I have a bit of an idea now, see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the read.spss function from the foreign package and set to.data.frame=TRUE and stringAsFactors=FALSE. The sji.viewSPSS function does not prevent converting string to factors, I might change that or add at least an option for this feature.

**Edit, due to new package developments**
You could now also try the [haven-package](https://github.com/hadley/haven/) (also on CRAN now) or [the updated sjPlot package](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/reading-from-and-writing-to-spss-sas-and-stata-with-r-rstats-sjplot/), which also uses haven's read functions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the sjPlot package to read the .sav file and see if you get the same error?

```
install.packages("sjPlot"); library(sjPlot)
df <- sji.SPSS(...)
sji.viewSPSS(df)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is something that worked for me, but I do not understand why. The answer is: in your spss file (variable view) change the width of the string variables to something shorter. Exactly how short is short enough is not clear enough and it even seems to vary between variables (?!) but when there are no really wide string variables any more the extra empty columns will also disappear. (And as a bonus we restict the amount of trailing blanks in the factor levels somewhat)

Comment: Just something else that might be useful for someone with more understanding: I never managed to import spss files without getting the (seemingly innocent) "Unrecognized record type 7, subtype 18 encountered in system file" warning. However, in the file that caused above problem for me (not the example of the OP) there were two other similar warnings: record type 7 subtype 14 and recrord type 7 subtype 21. 

Now for the interesting part: after I shortened all the string variables in spss not only did the problem disappear, but also the subtype 14 warning. (The other two are still there.)